# What formulas do I need to calculate the time it takes for a room with opened window to become the same temperature as outside?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, time, estimation, thermal-conductivity

I want to calculate how long I have to open my window to become the same temperature as outside.
To make things more easy let’s assume there’s almost no wind helping the exchange of temperature.

Comment: This is not a well defined problem. It will depend on the difference in temperature and  whether it is a room in a house and how many outside walls it has. For a room in a heated house you will never reach the outside temperature: the thermometer in a covered veranda next to the heated house is always at least 1C higher than the one next to an unheated one. The house radiates, including in the room with the open window.

Comment: for example look at this https://www.diydata.com/planning/ch_design/example1_imperial.php